# LabVIEW 2022 Offline Help Window?

Tags: window, offline, labview

How can I get Offline Help Window for LabVIEW 2022 Q3 Version, just like in LabVIEW 2021 and other previous versions?

Currently, when I click on Help > LabVIEW Help..., it shows a webpage like this:
[Online Help Window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0cZGf.png)

But I want it to show the older Help Window like this: [Offline Help Window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PNRat.png)

Is there any way to obtain the older Help Window for 2022 Version?

Answer (score 1):

No. LabVIEW 2022 shipped without offline help. The only way to have offline help would be to do a web crawl of NI's website and download the webpages to your local machine and then amend the URLs that you get when clicking help links in LV 2022 and redirect them to your local copy.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like should be possible to get the offline help by checking a checkbox in the help preferences, but it's the online help by default:

[image]

[image]

See the discussion here:
https://forums.ni.com/t5/LabVIEW/Offline-Help-window-in-LabVIEW-2022/m-p/4251163#M1236962